# I'm using D3, how do I rectify "t is not iterable error"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm receiving the following error in D3: `TypeError: t is not iterable at Object.H [as min]`

The code I've modified was from v3 but I think I've changed everything to v7.

I believe I've found what's causing the error but I'm at a loss as to why it's occurring and how to fix it.  Here's where I believe the issue is coming from, as when I change to code in both domain lines to `.domain([0,1])` the issue goes away.

```
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
        d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.AvgPerc; })]),
        d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.AvgPerc; })])
        ])
    .range([0,w])
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
        d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.ActualPerc; })]),
        d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.ActualPerc; })])
        ])
    .range([h,0])
```

And here's the full code for reference in case it's helpful (I also have an error with the xAxis and yAxis variables but one step at at time!):

```
  // Variables
  var body = d3.select('.d3block')
    var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 }
    var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom
    var w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right
    var formatDecimal = d3.format('.2')
    // Scales
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
        d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.AvgPerc; })]),
        d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.AvgPerc; })])
        ])
    .range([0,w])
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
        d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.ActualPerc; })]),
        d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.ActualPerc; })])
        ])
    .range([h,0])
    // SVG
    var svg = body.append('svg')
        .attr('height',h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr('width',w + margin.left + margin.right)
      .append('g')
        .attr('transform','translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    // X-axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .tickFormat(formatDecimal)
      .ticks(5)
      .orient('bottom')
  // Y-axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .tickFormat(formatDecimal)
      .ticks(5)
      .orient('left')
  // Circles
  var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('cx',function (d) { return xScale(d.AvgPerc) })
      .attr('cy',function (d) { return yScale(d.ActualPerc) })
      .attr('r','10')
      .attr('stroke','black')
      .attr('stroke-width',1)
      .attr('fill', 'rgb(139,71,38)')
```

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: Sure, below is a table (at least I think it will be), and I can upload a sample .csv but haven't done so before and don't see where that's an option here or in the main question.
EDIT: The formatting didn't work like I thought it would but you get the idea.

|Node|AvgPerc|ActualPerc|
---------------------------
|A      |0.8746   |0.4758      |
---------------------------
|B      | 0.5813   |0.1049     |
--------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was twofold, and both the original code and ksp's initial response (simplify to `d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.ActualPerc; })`)would have worked.

The two issues were:

1. the first line of my code which I omitted and should not have omitted was incorrect, I'd used `d3.csv('data.csv', function(data) {...})` whereas I should have used `d3.csv('data.csv').then(function(data) {...})`
2. `d3.svg.axis` did not work and had to be changed to `d3.axisBottom` and `.orient(bottom)` was removed

Thanks @ksp585 for the original help on the axis domains, the explanation clarified things!